# Create a function that returns different types with existing class inheritance

Tags: c++

So there are the following existing classes:

```
class Data {};

class String_data : public Data {
  string m_data;
    public:
  string str() { return m_data; }
};

class Integer_data : public Data {
  int m_data;
    public:
  int value() { return m_data; }
};
```

I am trying to do something like overloaded functions but for the base class:

```
string get_data(String_data *data) {
  return data->str();
}

int get_data(Integer_data *data) {
  return data->value();
}
```

The problem is that these objects are stored in a container as an object pointer of the base class like:

```
std::map<string, Data*> data_list;
data_list.emplace( std::pair<string, Data*>("first", new String_data()) );
data_list.emplace( std::pair<string, Data*>("second", new Integer_data()) );
```

So, i am trying to get it to work something like this:

```
string first_data = get_value(data_list["first"]);
int second_data = get_value(data_list["second"]);
```

Edit: Sorry this will have to get long. I wanted to keep the question simple but it won't quite work unless i state the full intention.

Some of the items in the data_list are pretty constant and i wanted to create an easy way to expand on the list of items without having to create a wrapper class and have separate access method for each of it like this:

```
class DataListWrapper {
  map<string, Data*> m_data_list;
public:
  string get_house() { return ((String_data*)m_data_list["house"])->str(); }
  int get_loan() { return ((Integer_data*)m_data_list["loan"])->value(); }
  // etc...
};
```

To make sure that these the developer won't accidentally mistype the string keys i created global constants for the compiler to check in compile-time.

```
#ifndef STRING_CONSTANTS
#define STRING_CONSTANTS
constexpr char c_house[] = "house";
constexpr char c_loan[] = "loan";
#endif
```

So, at the moment we do this:

```
string house = ((String_data*)m_data_list["house"])->str();
int loan = ((Integer_data*)m_data_list["loan"])->value();
call_me(house, loan);
```

But I want to expand on the list and easily get the value by just doing very simple and effortless something like:

```
string house = get_value(m_data_list[c_house]);
int loan = get_value(m_data_list[c_loan]);
call_me(house, loan)
```

Edit: In some sense i wanted to do it without type-casting as it gets really verbose and kind of blinds people away from what the code is trying to do with all the type-casting going on.

Comment: The problem is types need to be known at compile time. What happens if you replace `"first"` by a user provided string? It would not be possible to know the type of `data_list[key]` at compile time.

Comment: Usually you use `std::variant`-like for such things and not inheritance.

Comment: You can manually dispatch via `dynamic_cast`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that easily with `std::variant`, which keeps arount metadata that tells which type is used. So you can remove the empty base class:

```
using Data = std::variant<String_data, Integer_data>;

std::map<string, Data> data_list;

data_list.emplace("first", String_data{});
data_list.emplace("second", Integer_data{});
```

Then use a visitor that let you inspect the underlying data:

```
auto get_data(String_data const& data) -> std::string {
    return data.str();
}

auto get_data(Integer_data const& data) -> int {
    return data.value();
}

std::visit(
    [](auto& data) { auto value = get_data(data); },
    data_list["first"]
);

std::visit(
    [](auto& data) { auto value = get_data(data); },
    data_list["second"]
);
```

---

However, if you want to keep the class hierarchy, you can always implement your own visitor using virtual polymorphism:

```
struct Visitor {
    virtual void operator()(int const&) const = 0;
    virtual void operator()(std::string const&) const = 0;
};

struct PrintVisitor : Visitor {
    void operator()(int const& value) const override {
        std::cout << value;
    }

    void operator()(std::string const& value) const override {
        std::cout << value;
    }
};

struct Data {
    virtual void visit(Visitor const&) const = 0;
};

struct String_data : Data {
    void visit(Visitor const& v) const override {
        v(m_data);
    }

private:
    std::string m_data;
};

struct Integer_data : Data {
    void visit(Visitor const& v) const override {
        v(m_data);
    }

private:
    int m_data;
};
```

Then use it:

```
data_list["first"]->visit(PrintVisitor{});
data_list["second"]->visit(PrintVisitor{});
```

---

Of course, if you already know the types of your elements in the map, you can downcast them using `static_cast`. But it requires that you have enough context to know in advance which type there will be:

```
string first_data = get_value(static_cast<String_data*>((data_list["first"]));
int second_data = get_value(static_cast<Integer_data*>((data_list["second"]));

call_me(first_data, second_data);
```

I would advise against using `dynamic_cast`. When you are about to use dynamic casts, you better off using a variant. Downcast it that way imply you know the amount of types you'll deal with, and will constrain the hierarchy just like a variant, but in a more subtle and error prone way.

---

Since you added more detail to the question, the problem is clearer.

My solution would be to not use strings directy, and use some kind of identifier to encapsulate both how to cast and how to get the value.

```
struct house_data_t {
    static constexpr auto index = "house";
    using type = String_data; 
} inline constexpr house_data{};

struct loan_data_t {
    static constexpr auto index = "loan";
    using type = Integer_data; 
} inline constexpr loan_data{};
```

Then make a function that uses this metadata:

```
std::string house = get_value(house_data, data_list);
int loan = get_value(loan_data, data_list);
```

The `get_value` function can be implemented like that:

```
auto get_data(String_data* data) -> std::string {
    return data->str();
}

auto get_data(Integer_data* data) -> int {
    return data->value();
}

using data_list_t = std::map<std::string_view, std::unique_ptr<Data>>;


template<typename data_t, typename data_type_t = typename data_t::type>
auto get_value(data_t data, data_list_t& data_list) -> decltype(get_data(std::declval<data_type_t*>())) {
    return get_data(static_cast<data_type_t*>(data_list[data.index].get()));
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/PNXZMV)

Comment: So, what you essentially did was to create a virtual function for some other class to access the data with various overloaded forms. But I want to return the actual values not send a function to access the values. For example, i need to pass those values to another function now.

Comment: What will that other function accept? Are you planning on having it accept a variant type as well? It can't accept both int and string

Comment: Just a regular function that takes an int and a string. I don't want to turn this function to a visitor as it may already be used for something else. Think of something simple like f1(string s, int i);

Comment: @Guillaume see my edit to understand my intention and why i want it that way.

Comment: @user3689034 I updated the answer with a new section

Comment: @user3689034 also note that I used `static_cast`, since c-style casts are bad and will silently remove const or reinterpret.

Comment: I can't get it to compile. I get the error about 'no instance function template' on get_value(). I wonder if it is because i am using VS2017 but may work on other compilers. Do you actually mean map<...>? or was it just an abbreviation you were making for the full thing?

Comment: The `std::map<...>` is the type of your map `data_list`. I'll try compiling the code to see if there is errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192983/discussion-between-user3689034-and-guillaume-racicot).